# Resend in GMail

Tags: gmail

I'm looking for a resend feature in GMail Web, allowing me to take an email in my sent folder and send the exact same email to someone else.

GMail does not currently have this functionality: Clicking on "Forward" changes the body and the subject. So I'm looking for a "forward"-like feature, except that it should keep intact the subject and body.

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm looking for "forward"-like feature"? Do you mean a built-in feature or are you skin for script, add-on, web browser extension? Please bear in mind that asking for a software recommendation is off-topic in this site but they might be on-topic on [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 1):

I use Mozilla Thunderbird as my email client and there is a Forward option available under Sent Mail.

But using a browser to log into your Gmail account, open the sent item and click on the 3 dots **on the email itself** for More and there is a forward option there allowing you edit it before sending.

Comment: If this addresses your question please [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and consider upvoting as well to make it easier for other to find the reference. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. That's not what I was looking for, because it appends "---------- Forwarded message ---------" to the body and "Fwd: " to the subject. I clarified my question.

Comment: @LTR bit those additions can be edited out as explained in my answer.

Comment: Sure. I'm looking for a more elegant solution though. Surely someone has made an extension to do this.